# Concatening dataframes in for loop is very slow

Tags: python-3.x, performance

I'm merging excel files together based on a string resp. via a shared part of their filename:

```
filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xls"))

dd = defaultdict(list)
for fn in filenames:
    dd[fn.split('_202')[0]].append(fn)
    
dict_df = {}
for k, v in dd.items():
    dict_df[k] = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(fn
                                        , parse_dates = ['time']
                                        , dayfirst=True
                                        , skiprows=4
                                        , sep="\t"
                                        , decimal=','
                                        ).assign(Path = fn) for fn in v
                            ]
                           , ignore_index=True
                           )
```

But this is extremely slow. Is there a way to speed this up somehow? I assume there is a smarter way to proceed than I do above?

**edit:** I read, that `appending` would be much faster but tbh, I'm not so much into the data structures so I'm not sure how to set it up reasonably. I tried

```
dict_df2 = []
for k, v in dd.items():
    dict_df2.append(pd.read_csv(fn
                               , parse_dates = ['time']
                               , dayfirst=True
                               , skiprows=4
                               , sep="\t"
                               , decimal=','
                    ).assign(Path = fn) for fn in v)
```

but this doesn't work as this generates an object of the class `generator` (..?).

Comment: If your indentation correct as we see it? I ask because of how `fn` is defined and used here.

Comment: The indentations are correct, yes. fn is used twice as an iterator for for loops?

Comment: when you `pd.read_csv(fn,...` inside your second `for` loop, that is always the same value of `fn` i.e. the last value of `fn` from the prior `for` loop.

Comment: I guess thanks for the input but I'm not sure how to use this. Are you pointing me towards something? All I can say is that the command itself works :) It's just not efficient.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I missed `for fn in v`. My appologies

Answer (score 1):

I might try building a generator to yield rows into from each of the files. Here is a toy example and I'm not sure if it will help or not as I have not tried to `timeit`. If it does not let me know so I can delete this.

**Given test_202_data1.csv:**

```
test,time
foo1,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
foo2,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
foo3,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
foo4,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
foo5,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
foo6,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
foo7,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
foo8,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
foo9,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
```

**Given test_202_data2.csv:**

```
test,time
test,time
bar1,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
bar2,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
bar3,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
bar4,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
bar5,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
bar6,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
bar7,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
bar8,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
bar9,'2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
```

Then you might try:

```py
import glob
import pandas
import csv

def all_rows_from_files(filenames):
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename, "r") as file:
            yield from csv.DictReader(file)

filenames = glob.glob("./test/*.csv")

keyed_filenames = {}
for filename in filenames:
    key = filename.split('_202')[0]
    keyed_filenames.setdefault(key, []).append(filename)

keyed_dataframes = {
    key: pandas.DataFrame(all_rows_from_files(filenames))
    for key, filenames in keyed_filenames.items()
}

for key, value in keyed_dataframes.items():
    print("---------------")
    print(f"Key: {key}")
    print("Data:")
    print(value)
    print("---------------")
```

That should give you:

```
---------------
Key: ./test\test
Data:
    test                          time
0   foo1  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
1   foo2  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
2   foo3  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
3   foo4  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
4   foo5  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
5   foo6  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
6   foo7  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
7   foo8  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
8   foo9  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
9   bar1  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
10  bar2  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
11  bar3  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
12  bar4  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
13  bar5  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
14  bar6  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
15  bar7  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
16  bar8  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
17  bar9  '2023-06-07 08:59:34.903575'
---------------
```

Which I hope is faster that what you are doing now.